# Unity Voice Command in Android

Tags: android, unity3d, vr

Не могу найти информации в интернете о том, как можно осуществить голосовое управление в Android, много примеров Windows.Speech и подобных для ОС, для андроида не нашел, может вы поможете, кто уже задавался таким вопросом и есть какие то соображения, источники?